# Solve three equations with three unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve the system:
$$\begin{cases}a+b+c=6\\ab+ac+bc=11\\abc=6\end{cases}$$
The solution is:
$a=1,b=2,c=3$

How can I solve it?

Comment: now i have the solution from a book but i dont know how, i want someone explain the method for me

Comment: @J-rone `The solution is ...` Any permutation of $1,2,3$ is a solution as well e.g. $a=2,b=3,c=1$ since the equations are symmetric in $a,b,c$.

Comment: The upvotes are baffling considering this post has no context.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Not at all this is a 'Hot Network Question' hence the upvotes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without Vieta's formulas, the polynomial can be derived the hard way by elimination. From the first and last equations:

$$
b+c=6-a \\
bc = 6 / a
$$

Substituting the above into the middle equation:

$$
11=a(b+c)+bc=a(6-a)+6/a \;\;\iff\;\; a^3-6 a^2+11a - 6 = 0
$$

By inspection, the latter equation has $a=1$ as a root, then factoring out $a-1$ gives:

$$a^3-6 a^2+11a - 6=(a-1)(a^2-5a+6)=(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)$$

Since the original system is symmetric in $a,b,c$ it follows that the solutions are $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Nice, @dxiv  (out of votes for the next 3 and a half hours, but I'll make a point of keeping the tab open!)  This, I think, best establishes how to move from the given system of equations, to arrive at the solutions, as requested by the asker.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks. As a side note, the problem with questions like this one, posted without any context, is that it gives no clues about OP's background, or what kind of answer they are in fact looking for.

Comment: @dxiv They're looking for how to solve that system of equations. How complicated can that be?

Comment: @LastStar007 The most direct solution is the one-liner posted by Paolo Leonetti, but apparently the OP did not recognize Vieta's formulas (which is even more odd since the question was originally posted with the only tag `polynomials`). Point of my previous comment was that nowhere in the question is it hinted that brute-force system-solving techniques are preferred.

Comment: dxiv  I definitely recognized this, but it seemed quite clear to me that Paolo's answer never addressed the system of equations, and went no further that to related the given solutions to the a relevant equation; never addressing the process of solving a system of equations, so I wouldn't even call it direct in any sense of the term. Some folks answer to impress mathematicians, some are able to impress non-math, and math-folks alike.

Comment: Can someone explain a bit more how the factoring here $a^3−6a^2+11a−6=(a−1)(a^2−5a+6)$ works? How can I factor out the binomial from the polynomial?

Comment: @Max Lookup [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example), or [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#Regular_synthetic_division) for a shortcut. Or, do it by hand by isolating factors in $a-1$ starting from the left:

$$
a^3-6 a^2+11a - 6=a^3-a^2-5a^2+5a +6a-6=a^2(a-1)-5a(a-1)+6(a-1)
$$

Comment: Great thank you. How did you know to extract $(a - 1)$ though?

Comment: @Max As written in the answer, $a^3-6 a^2+11a - 6 = 0$ has $a=1$ as a root, which is pretty obvious by inspection, or could otherwise more systematically be determined using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Therefore $a^3-6 a^2+11a - 6$ must be divisible by $a-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, that clears it up for me!

Answer (score 15):

By using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the system is equivalent to say that $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-6x^2+11x-6$, which factorizes as $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. Hence $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 6):

For class work it is likely that the roots are integers, so I would just try them.  There are not many factorizations of $6$ and $1,2,3$ should jump out.  Then just try it and you are done.

The routine approach is substitution.  Write the first as $a=6-b-c$ and plug that into the other two.  Solve the second for $b$ and you have one (messy) equation in $c$.  The rational root theorem will work here.

Answer (score 5):

You should post your attempts at the question.

Try rearranging some things to fit them together.
$$\begin{cases}a+b+c=6\\ab+ac+bc=11\\abc=6\end{cases}$$

---

$$a+b+c=6$$
$$a+c=6-b$$

---

$$ab+ac+bc=11$$
$$b(a+c)+ac=11$$

---

$$b(a+c)+ac=11=b(6-b)+ac=11$$

$$ac=\frac{6}{b}$$
$$b(6-b)+ac=11=b(6-b)+\frac{6}{b}=11$$

now you have an equation dependent only upon b.

Rearrange it to find b.  Then substitute the answer for b into the other equations and rearrange and substitute to solve for a or c.  Then substitute that in with b and you can find whichever variable is left.

Answer (score 4):

By method of substitution:
$$\begin{cases} b+c=6-a \\ a(6-a)+\frac{6}{a}=11 \\ bc=\frac{6}{a}\end{cases} \Rightarrow$$
$$a^3-6a^2+11a-6=0 \Rightarrow (a-1)(a-2)(a-3)=0 \Rightarrow a=1; 2; 3.$$
Substituting these and solving $$\begin{cases} b+c=6-a \\ bc=\frac{6}{a}\end{cases}$$
six solutions will be found:
$$(a,b,c)=(1,2,3); (1,3,2); (2,1,3); (2,3,1); (3,1,2); (3,2,1).$$

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other derivations, here's my approach.

In the second equation, move everything to the left side, factor $ac+bc$ into $(a+b)c$, multiply everything by $c$, replace $a+b$ with $6-c $ from the first equation, and $abc$ with $6$ from the third. Then you have $6-11c+(6-c)c^2 = 0$, which simplifies to $c^3-6c^2+11c-6 = 0$, which has roots $1, 2,$ and $3$.